# How to do the Calculation by using Date format in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Appreciate your help for the below question, i have struggle for a long time for this question. Please look at the example below.

```
(SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN SI.DATE_STAT >= 78000000000000000 AND 
            SUBSTR(DIGITS(SI.DATE_STAT),5,2) BETWEEN '01' AND '12' AND 
            SUBSTR(DIGITS(SI.DATE_STAT),9,1) BETWEEN '0' AND '3' AND 
            INT(SUBSTR(DIGITS(SI.DATE_STAT),7,2)) BETWEEN 1 AND 
            DAY(DATE(CAST(19+INT(SI.DATE_STAT / 100000000000000000) AS CHAR(2)) || 
            TRANSLATE('YE-MN-01', DIGITS(SI.DATE_STAT), 'xxYEMNDA')) + 1 MONTH - 1 DAY)
            THEN TIMESTAMP(CAST(19+INT(SI.DATE_STAT / 100000000000000000) AS CHAR(2)) || 
            TRANSLATE('YE-MN-DA HR:UT:SC', DIGITS(SI.DATE_STAT),'xxYEMNDAxHRUTSC')) - 
            INT(MOD(3 - INT(SUBSTR(DIGITS(SI.DATE_STAT),9,1)),3)) DAYS + 
            INT(MOD(INT(SUBSTR(DIGITS(SI.DATE_STAT),16,2)) - 1,25) + 1) HOURS + 
            INT(MOD(4 - ((INT(SUBSTR(DIGITS(SI.DATE_STAT),16,2)) - 1) / 25),4) * 15) 
            MINUTES ELSE CAST(NULL AS TIMESTAMP)END) 
        FROM EXPORT.STAT_ITEM SI
        WHERE (SI.INVOICE_REF = SH.SHPMNT_REF) AND SI.STAT_CODE = 'ABC') AS ABC,

         (SELECT MIN(CASE WHEN SI.DATE_STAT >= 78000000000000000 AND 
            SUBSTR(DIGITS(SI.DATE_STAT),5,2) BETWEEN '01' AND '12' AND 
            SUBSTR(DIGITS(SI.DATE_STAT),9,1) BETWEEN '0' AND '3' AND 
            INT(SUBSTR(DIGITS(SI.DATE_STAT),7,2)) BETWEEN 1 AND 
            DAY(DATE(CAST(19+INT(SI.DATE_STAT / 100000000000000000) AS CHAR(2)) || 
            TRANSLATE('YE-MN-01', DIGITS(SI.DATE_STAT), 'xxYEMNDA')) + 1 MONTH - 1 DAY)
            THEN TIMESTAMP(CAST(19+INT(SI.DATE_STAT / 100000000000000000) AS CHAR(2)) || 
            TRANSLATE('YE-MN-DA HR:UT:SC', DIGITS(SI.DATE_STAT),'xxYEMNDAxHRUTSC')) - 
            INT(MOD(3 - INT(SUBSTR(DIGITS(SI.DATE_STAT),9,1)),3)) DAYS + 
            INT(MOD(INT(SUBSTR(DIGITS(SI.DATE_STAT),16,2)) - 1,25) + 1) HOURS + 
            INT(MOD(4 - ((INT(SUBSTR(DIGITS(SI.DATE_STAT),16,2)) - 1) / 25),4) * 15) 
            MINUTES ELSE CAST(NULL AS TIMESTAMP)END) 
        FROM EXPORT.STAT_ITEM SI
        WHERE (SI.INVOICE_REF = SH.SHPMNT_REF) AND SI.STAT_CODE = 'DEF') AS DEF,

//This should be wrong and I'm getting error.
coalesce((days(DEF) -  days(ABC)),'0') as TotalTransitTime
```

What I wan is to show the date betweeen "DEF" and "ABC" and the default will be 0 if DEF or ABC is missing. Please help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is the SQL error you are getting ?

Comment: @MebinJoe this error i get " 1) [Code: -206, SQL State: 42703]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=DEF, DRIVER=4.19.49. 2) [Code: -727, SQL State: 56098]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-206;42703;DEF, DRIVER=4.19.49"

Comment: Those errors look like DB2, not Oracle. Should you fix tags?

Comment: do you need to add two dates or calculate the difference between two dates ?

Comment: @MebinJoe both i need

Comment: What do you mean by : "The date betweeen "DEF" and "ABC" " Is that the number of days?

Comment: for example you can add 10 days to current date by this query: SELECT CURRENT_DATE + 10 FROM DUAL;

Comment: @Rene Yes, Correct...I need to calculate the days betwen DEF date and ABC date

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620592/how-to-calculate-difference-between-two-dates-in-oracle-11g-sql